# Null Pointer exception when initilizing socket

Tags: android

I have created one android Bluetooth program which communicates with serial port. In my program I have 3 buttons: Connect, Select & Disconnect. Connect is used for enabling Bluetooth. Select is used for retrieving data from serial port. Disconnect is for disconnecting Bluetooth and the socket which I obtained to retrieve data, and to initialize the socket as null.

```
btnDisConnect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
    public void onClick(View v) {  
        try{            
            mBluetoothAdapter.disable();
            mmSocket.close();
            mmSocket=null;                                 
        } catch(Exception e) {
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to Close.Try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
});
```

My problem is when I tried to initialize the socket as null it shows Null Pointer exception.
I want to  make this socket as null for further work. How can I make it null on buttonclick?

Comment: You write about trouble initializing but you have posted code where you disconnect.

Comment: Are you sure that the socket is not null when you invoke "mmSocket.close()" ? Surround it with "if (mmSocket != null) { .. }"

Comment: Please post a logcat with the error. I don't think the problem is with the code you've posted.

Comment: no it not that line causing troubling. Assignment can not throw exception

Comment: mBluetoothAdapter.disable(); is causing the issue, call this after disconnecting the socket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remember to close your Input/output streams first, then close the socket.

By closing the streams, you kick off the disconnect process. After you close the socket, the connection should be fully broken down.

If you close the socket before the streams, you may be bypassing certain shutdown steps, such as the (proper) closing of the physical layer connection.

Here's the method I use when its time to breakdown the connection.

```
/**
 * Reset input and output streams and make sure socket is closed. 
 * This method will be used during shutdown() to ensure that the connection is properly closed during a shutdown.  
 * @return
 */
private void resetConnection() {
        if (mBTInputStream != null) {
                try {mBTInputStream.close();} catch (Exception e) {}
                mBTInputStream = null;
        }

        if (mBTOutputStream != null) {
                try {mBTOutputStream.close();} catch (Exception e) {}
                mBTOutputStream = null;
        }

        if (mBTSocket != null) {
                try {mBTSocket.close();} catch (Exception e) {}
                mBTSocket = null;
        }

}
```